# Auto increment on a button?

Tags: php, html, increment

first of all, I'm starting html and my english is a bit bad.
I wanna know if it's possible to increment a value from a button ?
In facts, I have a button which impress :

```
<input id="impress" name="impress" type="button" onclick="imprimer_page();refresh();";  value="Impress" /> </input></td>
<script type="text/javascript">
function impress_page(){
window.print();
}
function reload(){
javascript:window.location.reload();
}
```

I've found these two function on Internet and it works. Then, my question is, is it possible to increment a value everytime we click on this button ?
If it's possible in other languages as CSS, Java or Php, i take ! :)

Thank you.

Comment: you can save the value in `cookie` or `localstorage`

Comment: Your question is little to wide to answer. because THE value can be store in multiple places and yes, it is possible to update in all or either place. You need to learn more of Web basic and reframe your question to be specific include what you want to achieve to assist you on "How to do .. ".

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the value from a input text field, increment the value in an JavaScript-function and put it back in the input field, maybe like this:

```
function inc()
{
    var new_value = (parseInt(document.getElementById("v1").value) + 1);
    document.getElementById("v1").value = parseInt(new_value);
}
```

"v1" is the id of the input text field, you have to set it. Call the function with the onclick-attribute, like you did above.